# MyPy and sqlalchemy - "Session" has no attribute "__enter__"; maybe "__iter__"? Mypyattr-defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy, sqlalchemy-stubs

I recently updated mypy configuration for my python 3.11 project, adding an .ini file to check my already working sql alchemy code. **I'm using sqlalchemy == 2.0.29**

It oddly started complaining about this line of code:

[image]

```py
with Session(db) as session:
    ...
```

the 'db' variable is being used as per [SQlalchemy 2.0 docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html):

```py
db = create_engine(db_string)
```

Here is the MyPy error in detail:

[image]

```
"Session" has no attribute "__enter__"; maybe "__iter__"? [attr-defined]
"Session" has no attribute "__exit__" [attr-defined]
```

While this is my current mypy.ini file:

```ini
[mypy]
python_version = 3.11
ignore_missing_imports = True
plugins = sqlmypy
```

Why is mypy complaining about that perfectly working line of code?

Comment: `sqlmypy` hasn't been updated in years and never made it past alpha. It's very incomplete.

Comment: If you were to remove the `plugins = sqlmypy` line and uninstall the package you would see no errors at all.

Comment: Its complaining about it because the object represented by Session(db) does not meet the criteria for working with the with statement.  That object should have entry and exist dunder methods to allow control of the resource it manages.

Comment: BTW,  I suggest actually showing the entirety of the code.   It would have helped to see how Session was defined in that file.

Comment: @LhasaDad: Session objects *do* have those methods, though.